# Is there a limit to validations in a Backpack controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Laravel has powerful and elegant validation features like [unique/ignore/where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-unique). And Backpack's CRUD controllers allow for [invoking Laravel validation](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/crud-operation-create#validation-1) from within the controller.

It's clear to me how to invoke simple validation rules like `required` within the Backpack controller. But what about something complex like

```
Rule::unique('users')
->ignore($user->id)
->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('location_id', 1);
})
```

Is there a way to invoke that complex validation from within a Backpack CRUD controller? Or is this a case where I *must* define the validation in the Request, not the CRUD controller?

Is there documentation somewhere that defines which specific Laravel validation techniques are possible within a Backpack controller, and which aren't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further testing, I've determined that there are indeed some more rules to follow. But first, here's a more extensive pattern that works fine:

```
//
// This field uses ->setValidation()
//
    CRUD::field('name_group')
        -> label('Group') ;

    $rules = [
            'name_group' => 
                [ 
                'required',
                Rule::unique('groups') -> ignore( request('id') ),
                ],
            ] ;
    $messages = [
        'name_group.required' => 
            'Please enter a name for this Group.',
        'name_group.unique' => 
            'The name for this Group must be unique.',
                ] ;

    CRUD::setValidation( $rules, $messages ) ;
//
// This field uses ->validationRules()
//
    CRUD::field('notes')
        -> validationRules('required')
        -> validationMessages([
            'required' => 'Please enter some notes for this Group.',
            ]) ;
//
// This is another field that uses ->setValidation()
//
    CRUD::field('description') ;

    $rules = [
        'description' => 
            [ 
            Rule::unique('groups') -> ignore( request('id') ),
            ],
        ] ;
    $messages = [
        'description.unique' => 
            'The description for this Group must be unique.',
                ] ;
    
    CRUD::setValidation( $rules, $messages ) ;
```

So the rules seem to be:

1. You can use `setValidation()` on a field-by-field basis within a controller. Each call to `setValidation()` appears to be cumulative with respect to earlier calls, so nothing gets lost when you call `setValidation()` a second time.
2. Within that same controller, a field with simpler validation needs can use `->validationRules()` *instead of* `setValidation()`. In other words, you can mix-and-match freely on a field-by-field basis within a given controller.
3. What you ***cannot*** do is use *both* validation techniques for a single field! My testing suggests that `setValidation()` "wipes out" any `validationRules()` on the most recent `CRUD::field()` statement. So as long as you don't mix-and-match validation techniques *within a single field* you should be fine.

If someone who is expert in the internals of Backpack could comment on whether everything I wrote above is correct and complete, or not, that would be very helpful to all Backpack users, I'm sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this one, let me know if it works for you.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

....
protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        // CRUD::setValidation(UserRequest::class);
        $ignore = request('id') != null ? request('id') : null ;

        $this->crud->setValidation([
            'username' => [
                Rule::unique('users')
                ->ignore($ignore)
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('location_id', 1);
                })
            ],
        ]);

        .....
    }
```

change the 'username' to your specific field 
Reference: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/release-notes#quickly-validate-forms-inside-crudcontroller-no-formrequest-need

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @christmex. You definitely got me pointed in the right direction.

After much more research and tinkering, I got the following working in the CRUD controller for the Groups table:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule ;
...
    protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::setValidation(GroupRequest::class) ;  // Just in case I decide to use it

        // Set up rules and messages for name_group field
        $rules = [
                'name_group' => 
                    [ 
                    'required',
                    Rule::unique('groups') -> ignore( request('id') ),
                    ],
                ] ;
        $messages = [
            'name_group.required' => 
                'Please enter a name for this Group.',
            'name_group.unique' => 
                'The name for this Group must be unique.',
                    ] ;
        CRUD::field('name_group') -> label('Group')
            ;
        // This MUST be called AFTER the fields are defined, never before.
        // See https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/release-notes#define-validation-rules-directly-on-fields
        CRUD::setValidation( $rules, $messages ) ;
```

This works well -- `name_group` is required, and it must be unique, and the above code makes Backpack behave accordingly.

So it's looking like the answer to my original question is No, there are no limits to validations in a Backpack controller. If you can express it using Laravel's `Rule::` facade, you can set it in a Backpack controller.

However, I'm going to continue work on this pattern, as I'm not exactly clear whether this exact pattern will interact properly with other validations on other fields. You may indeed be able to set any validation in a Backpack controller, but there may be some specific coding rules you have to follow.

We'll see ... I'll report back later.